# Can't hide center image inside a tab bar

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm using this code as my tab bar class which gives me a custom tab bar with a bigger center button. My problem is when I try to hide the tab bar the tab bar disappears but the center button image stays visible. How can I hide the middle button with the tab bar?

```
[self addCenterButtonWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hood.png"] highlightImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hood-selected.png"] target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
```

....

```
- (void)addCenterButtonWithImage:(UIImage *)buttonImage highlightImage:(UIImage *)highlightImage target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0) {
        button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    } else {

        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;

    }

    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

**Update:**

From another class I wrote:

```
TabBarController *blah = [[WBTabBarController alloc]init];
[blah hideButton];
```

....

**TabBarController.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton* button;
```

**TabBarController.m:**

```
self.button = button;
```

...

```
-(void)hideButton
{
    _button.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"Test!!!");
}
```

But it doesn't work. If I put `_button.hidden = YES;` in viewDidLoad of TabBarController the button is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self.button removeFromSuperView]

or button.hidden=YES

when you add a subview like you have here [self.view addSubview:button]; and you then want to remove it you would normally do [self.button removeFromSuperView];

in the method where you hide your tabbar put [self.button removeFromSuperView]; does this also not work?

Comment: That gave me a direction. Still no solution, I've updated the first post